# "As I go" expression

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions

Could anyone please tell me what "as I go" means?

Like in the following context:

> I will fill it out as I go.

Comment: In this sense, it means "As I progress"; similar to "When I cook, I clean as I go" (meaning, by the time I'm done cooking, there's nothing left to clean, either, because I've been cleaning the entire time I've been cooking).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more context, it could mean:

*I will fill it out before I go.*
or
*I will fill it out while I am leaving.*

**EDIT**

As *Dan Bron* pointed out, an alternative is 
 *I will fill it out on the fly.*
or
*I will fill it out as I do something else.*

Additional context will resolve the amiguity.

Comment: It seems to me that is means "on the fly": doing something in an impromptu/on the spot manner (So, as you progress, as was explained in the comment by Dan Bron). In other words, you don't try to predict anything and just do it, deciding that you will resolve any issues that arise at the moment they do so.

Comment: This is completely different from @Matt Gutting's answer. Now you guys confused us :) which one is correct? To me both sounded logical, but his is more fun :) But what is the correct answer?

Comment: @TolgaEvcimen  To me they are the same... **The key issue is doing things in parallel rather than doing them sequentially.**

Comment: But your first example does not fit in your explanation. Does it?

Comment: @TolgaEvcimen The first is an alternative.  For example:  *I will make a donation as I go.* could mean: *I will make a donation as I am leaving the building.*  That is why **more** context is needed to resolve the ambiguity.

Comment: I see, so you are saying it can mean both. Thanks.

Comment: @TolgaEvcimen I was not clear in my answer.......I will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

*To do something as you go* is *to do the action in parallel with preparatory work for the action*, or for parts of it.

For example:

> I will fill out the form as I go.

means

> Instead of gathering all information first and then transferring it all to the form, I will gather some of the information and transfer that to the form, then gather more information and transfer that to the form, repeating until the form is complete.

Comment: This is completely different from @Gary's Student's answer. Now you guys confused us :) which one is correct? To me both sounded logical, but yours is more fun :) But what is the correct answer?